# Open all files in a folder

Tags: vim

Suppose you'd like to open all the files in your checkout folder under the /trunk subdirectory. Assume the files are called first.c second.r third.cpp. How can you open all the files into vim with a single command.

The obvious answer is the following

```
$ vim first.c second.r third.cpp
```

But can you do this more simply?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like you're on linux or some Unix variant.
Using the asterisk gets you all files in the current folder:

```
$ vim *
```

Comment: stackoverflow is truly a wonder in the modern era. Your solution is simple, easy to remember and works.

Comment: @Milktrader, you do realise its a shell thing and not a vim thing, right?. How do you copy _all_ the files in a folder? `cp * /some/other/place`. How do you delete _all_ the files in a folder? `rm *` etc.

Comment: This will not open dot files by default. For all files you need `{,.}*` (in bash, assuming that exists at least one file that start with a dot) or `(|.)*` (in zsh, works even if there are no dot files).

Comment: Check out the vim man page for some more info about using command line arguments to vim.  I like `vim * -p` to open in tabs, or `vim -O fileA fileB` to open a couple of files in a split view.  If they are similar I might use `vimdiff file{old,new}` to open them in a split view with the differences highlighted.

Comment: David - I will check out vim man now that I know that information lies therein, thanks. The extra information you posted is particularly useful. Jeff- I see how you characterize this as a shell question. vim and shell are very closely related so knowing one helps with operating the other. I characterized it as a vim question on the basis of accomplishing a specific task in vim, on which I was stumped. Next time I'll look for answers in shell and vim forums.

Comment: I want to open them all in tabs :'(

Answer (score 32):

To edit all files in the current folder, use:

```
vim *
```

To edit all files in tabs, use:

```
vim -p *
```

To edit all files in horizontally split windows, use:

```
vim -o *
```

Comment: vim -p * did the job for me

Comment: For completeness sake: To edit all files in _vertically_ split windows, use `vim -O *`  And to close everything use the classic `:qa`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answers given above, I'd like to point out that you can also do that from inside vim itself using

```
:args *
```

which sets the arglist to be the name of the files in the directory, and then you can display them in tabs with `:tab all` (or you can use `:argdo tabe`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible for the second command to open them all in new tabs as to not replace existing tabs?

Answer (score 9):

The other answers will not work if you have subdirectories. If you need to open all files in all subdirectories you can use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
vim `find . -type f`
```

If you want to ignore files in subdirectories write:

```
vim `find . -type f -depth 1`
```

You can, of course, get as fancy as you want using the `find` command.

Answer (score 5):

Edit all files using a given pattern:

```
vim `find . -name "*your*pattern*here*"`
```

Super useful when I do this:

```
vim `find . -name "*.go"`
```

Answer (score 2):

durum's answer is incomplete. To open all files in the directory without opening files in subdirectories, use this:

```
vim `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
```