# What does -p mean when launching vim in bash?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

I'm looking for a simple explanation. I've already scoured the internet but I found nothing satisfactory. I know I use it to open multiple files in Vim in tabs, so I'm assuming it pipes everything into an array of some sort and Vim takes that argument and opens everything up in tabs.

[Open all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081332/open-all-files-in-a-folder#comment3158873_3081336)

Comment: `-p` as an option to *which* command? `bash` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Vim docs:

> -p[N]  Open N tab pages.  When N is omitted, open one tab page for each file.

It's nothing to do with Bash, and everything to do with Vim.  Whatever arguments you pass to Vim are filenames, with or without the `-p` option.  The `-p` option controls whether all the files appear in tabs or if you have to switch between them in a single window.