# Vim : Open all .c and .h in all subdirectories

Tags: vim

I am on Linux. I am aware of this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081332/open-all-files-in-a-folder).

I have a few subdirectories, e.g. /inc, /libs, /src ... and I would like to open all *.c *and* all *.h files in all subdirectories, into one single Vim session at once.

To open only one sort of files from all subdirectories, this works well :    `` vim -O2 `find . -name "*.c"` `` (I usually use -O2 option, but it is not important here).

How can I extend the above to open both .c and .h files in all directories (but no other type of files)?

EDIT : As @phd suggests, this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079946/vim-open-all-c-and-h-in-all-subdirectories) shows how to load all the .c and .h *from within vim*. That's nice, but I am looking for a shell command to open a vim session with all the files preloaded, which is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way for vim to open all .C and .H files in a directory and all its subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877898/is-there-a-way-for-vim-to-open-all-c-and-h-files-in-a-directory-and-all-its-su)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+open+all+files+subdirectories

Comment: Thanks @phd. I'll look at this solution which allows to open the files while in vim (actually I can't get the solution to work, but I'm sure it's just me), but what I was looking for is a single shell command to open all the files in one vim session, which I do not think is address by other post.

Comment: `**` works in bash too, you have to enable [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) and then `vim **/*.c **/*.h`

Comment: Thanks @phd. Indeed this works! Happy to accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` turn on double star to list all files in all subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Now run `vim` with all files:

```
vim **/*.h **/*.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```sh
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -exec vim {} \+
```

[find (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) says:

```
-exec command {} +
  This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the 
  selected files, but the command line is built by appending each
  selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the
  command will be much less than the number of matched files.
```

This means that command above will execute `vim` command for found files by this way: `vim src/file1.c src/file2.c include/file.h`.

Comment: @ jubnzv. This works, thanks. I was wondering if there is a bit more "idiomatic" way to do this in vim by any chance. I'll give it another few days just in case, otherwise I'll accept your answer.